# ActiveXObject is throwing error when there is no add-on added for the page in IE

Tags: javascript

I have installed a third party plugins and switch it to status = enable. 
But I removed all sites from approved add-on list (Mange Add-ons> Select Plugin>More Info> click on "Remove all site").
Is there a easy to detect plugin in IE without approved add-on for the webpage?

So far in the Javascript file

If the browser is IE

```
function isPluginsInstalled(){
try {
   var o = new ActiveXObject("xx.xxplugins");
        o = null;
        return true;

    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
```

but I am getting "Automation server can't create object" error message.

Is there any other way to detect installed plugins except using ActiveXObject.